# django admin foreignkey icons not active

Tags: django, django-admin

In the django admin (4.2) I can find in case of foreignkey fields the icons for editing, adding, deleting and viewing the relevant foreignkey element. However, only the add button is active in my case. How can I activate the other icons=

Answer (score 0):

it turned out it was not directly caused by django but that those icons came from crispy-forms - crispy itself was already updated but I had to update the crispy template packs - now it is working again